# list only five files per archive recursively : ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I am using below command to get the detailed list of files in each archive in a particular directory. unzip -l "*.zip*". But the problem with this command is that it is enlisting all the files in the archive. I want to limit the number of files to be listed to 5 per archive.
I am using ssh. Thanks.:)

Answer (score 2):

you can either use `head` or `tail` to limit the top n line or bottom n line

```
unzip -l a.zip | head -n 5
```

Comment: Thanks:). But it is enlisting only top 5 lines. and I want to enlist top 5 files(when in ascending order) from each archive.

Comment: how do you unzip all the archives?

Comment: I am not unzipping the archives, unzipping file names in archive only using unzip -l "*.zip".

Comment: then you can do something like this - find . -name "*.zip" -maxdepth 1 -exec sh -c 'unzip -l {} | head -n 5' \;